# How to use apex toolkit to control sender/signer notifications?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

I’m looking to control sender/signer notifications using apex toolkit. How can this be completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send notifications with the [Notifications](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/notifications.html) class in the Apex Toolkit. After creating an instance of the Notification you can add it to your envelope with the [withNotifications](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/envelope.html) method on the Envelope class.

Comment: How about disabling notifications? The sender currently receives a notification whenever the document is completed by the signer. The sender does not want to receive a notification whenever the document is completed by the signer. I have disable all sender notifications in DocuSign Sender/Signer Notifications, however, the notifications are still coming over.